# "Small" 4K LCD monitors (<24 inch)?

Tags: monitors

What small small 4k monitors are available that are less than 24 inches?  The smaller and more affordable the better.

- **Less than (i.e. not including)** 24 inch nominal size (a 23.8 inch diagonal is a "24 inch" display)
- Minimum 4k (3840x2160) resolution
- No constraint on aspect ratio
- Available to consumers now or some time in the past (could buy used)
- Include a price if available
- Manufacturer links please

I know of these:

- [Astro 9.6in 4k](http://www.astrodesign.co.jp/english/product/dm-3409-a) - 3840x2160
- [IBM T220/T221](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IBM_T220/T221_LCD_monitors) - 3840×2400 (WQUXGA),

A related question has been asked, but requested specific and larger sizes:
[High DPI 21“ or 23” monitor for 13" MacBook Pro](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/510/high-dpi-21-or-23-monitor-for-13-macbook-pro/514#514)

Comment: Interestingly there's a few laptops (ranging down to 12 inches) with panels that would fit your needs, but I can't think of any consumer displays under 24 inches. My own research seems to suggest that at regular viewing distances, 4k is optimal at 27" size... http://superuser.com/questions/990799/will-the-pixel-density-difference-be-visible-between-4k-and-2k-monitors-at-27-s/991823#991823 if you're curious. https://www.adafruit.com/products/1652 is the closest thing I can think of that's modern but not quite there. What do you want to use this for?

Comment: As a general-purpose desktop display (naturally with a shorter viewing distance) and potentially attached to a VESA wall mount.

Comment: Exactly my question, I was trying to find a side-monitor for the 27" iMac where 24" is too big, likely 21-22 should be the sweet spot for using it in portrait mode and BORDERLESS (no bezel)

Answer (score 2):

I found that LG has recently released a [22" (21.5" Diagonal) UltraFine™ 4K IPS LED Monitor](http://www.lg.com/us/monitors/lg-22MD4KA-B-4k-uhd-led-monitor) that has a resolution of 4096 x 2304.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't recommend going for a 24 in 4k as it isn't recommended for the eye.

Check out the [Dell P2415Q](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjopKHvnsrKAhWIC44KHfyNAKAQFggcMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Faccessories.us.dell.com%2Fsna%2Fproductdetail.aspx%3Fc%3Dus%26cs%3D04%26l%3Den%26sku%3D860-BBFF&usg=AFQjCNGMUOPIv0HVsFfFAqS2PAAQMc7X5Q&sig2=vYNMv4wqXrv2a3QZze0ZlA) if you don't change your mind and go for a 24 in monitor. It is priced at around 425 dollars for which you can get good TV.

Comment: Can you add more reasons why you recommend this monitor? Also, ebpa is looking for 23" and smaller monitors. This is too big.

Comment: I own and regularly use Dell's P2415Q and UP2414Q monitors.  Personally I prefer the UP2414Q model because they cause me fewer problems after their power is interrupted at the power strip and they have tactile non-capacitive buttons.  They are both good monitors (which I would recommend), but as @Cfinley pointed out I'm asking about smaller monitors.

Comment: Why do you say higher pixel density isn't good for the eye?  Modern operating systems do display scaling, so things are legible regardless of your pixel density.

Comment: The cost goes up as they try to squeeze in more pixels within a smaller body. When you have a lot of pixels it strains your eye if you are not used to it

Comment: try the dell xps 13/15 4k variants

Comment: Real life is like a 24" 8k monitor, actually an infinity-k monitor, so that must really strain your eye ;)  (Unless, of course, you have special glasses that pixelate your world.)

Comment: I use daily a 13" 4k display on my Lenovo Yoga 3 Pro laptop and appreciate the pixels.  (Granted, I have it flipped backward so it is closer to me.)  I don't understand why they don't make smaller 15"-17" 4K monitors, as I want to have an array of them and not have them take up too much space.  Also, now we have cell phones that are higher than FHD.

Comment: These kinds of answers are simply not helpful. You do not know what the OPs requirements are. For me, I'm looking for a 21" 4k that I can run at Retina (2x) scaling, making everything appear the effective size of a 1080p display.

Answer (score 0):

SmallHD has a 22" 4K OLED monitor, MON-OLED-22, widely available, for the small price of 12 000 US dollars.

https://smallhd.com/products/oled22

The Panasonic Toughpad 4K Tablet is 20" and the [specs](https://pna-b2b-storage-mkt.s3.amazonaws.com/computer/toughpad4k/toughpad-4k_specsheet.pdf) mention HDMI 2.0 input on the "standard" model, the FZ-Y1. I still see it at some places around 2200 USD, eBay has a few for similar, it's an old one.

Answer (score 0):

The [LG 24UD58-B](https://www.lg.com/us/monitors/lg-24UD58-B-4k-uhd-led-monitor) is a 23.8" 2160p (4k) monitor. It has a maximum 60 Hz refresh rate and FreeSync adaptive framerate support for between 40-60 Hz. It is also relatively expensive and can be bought for less than $300 new. It is a good size to run at 2x scaling for an "effective" 1080p resolution for sharp text.